# Чем открыть проект .cbproj?

Tags: c++

Достался проект с расширением .cbproj. В VS не открывается как цельный проект. Не подскажете в какой среде создаются проекты с таким расширением и чем его открыть?

Comment: Гугл говорит, что это C++ Builder.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно файл CBPROJ которого касается проблема поврежден. Попробуйте открыть его через C++ Builder.

Comment: Это который embarcadero C++ Builder?

Comment: Да, он самый. https://www.embarcadero.com/ru/products/cbuilder/starter